# Owl carousel in bootstrap panel issue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tabs, carousel

I have a problem. I'm using owl carousel in bootstrap panel (in top of the footer www.bayern.ge check the link). when user clicks on second tab, owl carousel items have very small width and height. if you zoom page (change resolution), it gets good width and height. can anyone help me by solving this problem? Sorry for poor English.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34215877/owl-carousel-v2-item-width-calculated-wrong-if-the-carousel-behind-tab-content/40923801

Answer (score 1):

I work with this problem.

You must init owl again after change tab, something like this:

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
  owl.init();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:
Downgraded to Owl carousel v1.3.3